# Removing completely separated observations from glm()

Tags: r, subset, logistic-regression, glm

I'm doing a bit of exploratory data analysis using `HMDA` data from the `AER` package; however, the variables that I used to fit the model seem to contain some observations that perfectly determine the outcomes, an issue known as "separation." So I tried to remedy this using the solution recommended by [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336424/issue-with-complete-separation-in-logistic-regression-in-r), yet when I tried to execute the first set of source code from `glm.fit()`, R returned an error message:

```
Error in family$family : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

so I could not proceed any further to remove those fully determined observations from my data with this code. I am wondering if anyone could help me fix this?

My current code is provided at below for your reference.

```css
# load the AER package and HMDA data
library(AER)
data(HMDA)

# fit a 2-degree olynomial probit model 
probit.fit <- glm(deny ~ poly(hirat, 2), family = binomial, data = HMDA)

# using the revised source code from that stackexchage thread to find out observations that received a warning message
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

eps <- 10 * .Machine$double.eps
if (family$family == "binomial") {
  if (any(mu > 1 - eps) || any(mu < eps)) 
    warning("glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred", 
            call. = FALSE)
}

# this return the following error message
# Error in family$family : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable


probit.resids <- augment(probit.fit) %>%
  mutate(p = 1 / (1 + exp(-.fitted)),
         warning = p > 1-eps)

arrange(probit.resids, desc(.fitted)) %>%  
  select(2:5, p, warning) %>% 
  slice(1:10)


HMDA.nwarning <- filter(HMDA, !probit.resids$warning)

# using HMDA.nwarning should solve the problem...
probit.fit <- glm(deny ~ poly(hirat, 2), family = binomial, data = HMDA.nwarning)
```

Comment: Hi @ChrisT. , in the post, he was only looking at the code for the binomial regression in "family$family == "binomial"... " you don't need to run that

Comment: so it's only 1 observation is removed, see dim(HMDA.nwarning) and dim(HMDA)

Comment: @StupidWolf   but which `family` option should I run to tell R to look for perfectly separated observations in order to remove them?

Comment: @StupidWolf  they specified `"family$family == "binomial"` because they wanted to fix that logit regression, and one would need that code block to generate `eps` in order to generate `probit.resids$warning` to remove perfectly separated observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chunk of code

```
if (family$family == "binomial") {
  if (any(mu > 1 - eps) || any(mu < eps)) 
    warning("glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred", 
            call. = FALSE)
}
```

there is a function, `binomial()` called when you run glm with family == "binomial". If you look under `glm` (just type `glm`):

```
if (is.character(family)) 
        family <- get(family, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame())
    if (is.function(family)) 
        family <- family()
    if (is.null(family$family)) {
        print(family)
        stop("'family' not recognized")
    }
```

And the glm function checks binomial()$family during the fit, and if any of the predicted values differ from 1 or 0 by eps, it raises that warning.

You don't need to run that part, and yes, you need to set `eps <- 10 * .Machine$double.eps` . So let's run the code below, and if you run a probit, you need to specify `link="probit"` in binomial, otherwise the default is logit:

```
library(AER)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

data(HMDA)

probit.fit <- glm(deny ~ poly(hirat, 2), family = binomial(link="probit"), data = HMDA)

eps <- 10 * .Machine$double.eps

probit.resids <- augment(probit.fit) %>%
  mutate(p = 1 / (1 + exp(-.fitted)),
         warning = p > 1-eps)
```

The column warning indicates if the observations raises a warning, in this dataset, there's one:

```
table(probit.resids$warning)

FALSE  TRUE 
 2379     1
```

We can use the next step to filter it

```
HMDA.nwarning <- filter(HMDA, !probit.resids$warning)
dim(HMDA.nwarning)
[1] 2379   14
```

And rerun the regression:

```
probit.fit <- glm(deny ~ poly(hirat, 2), family = binomial(link="probit"), data = HMDA.nwarning)
coefficients(probit.fit)
(Intercept) poly(hirat, 2)1 poly(hirat, 2)2 
      -1.191292        8.708494        6.884404
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much for clarifying this. It really helps.